# How many equavalent axiomized systems of first order Peano arithmics can we construct?

Tags: number-theory, logic, proof-theory

Obviously, we can have more than one axiomized systems that are equivalent to first-order Peano arithmetics

How many equivalent axiomized systems of first order Peano arithmics can we construct?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose our language has size $\kappa$ with $\kappa$ infinite (the case when our language is finite will be the same as when our language is countably infinite - this is a quick exercise).

Given a set of sentences $T$, let $T'$ be the set gotten by removing all the tautologies from $T$. Let $Taut$ denote the set of tautologies. Since $Taut$ has cardinality $\kappa$ (why?), it has $2^\kappa$-many subsets. For each $S\subseteq Taut$, let $T_S=T'\cup S$. Then:

- Each $T_S$ is equivalent to $T$ (= every sentence provable from $T$ is provable from $T_S$, and vice versa) (= every model of $T$ is a model of $T_S$, and vice versa).
- There are $2^\kappa$-many theories of the form $T_S$.

Since there are only $2^\kappa$-many theories in the language $L$ in the first place, this shows:

> Every theory can be axiomatized in as many ways as is conceivably possible.

Note that PA has no special role here.